# how to get all users from table user that have timeend in enrol_more table greater than a specific value

Tags: sql, where-clause

[user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0dyJ.jpg)

[enrol_more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDamV.jpg)

i hope my question is clear

Comment: What have you tried and how is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select u.* from users u
inner join enrol_more e
on (u.id = e.userid)
where timeend > --specific value ;
```

Comment: this query returns me multiple times the same user. What i would like is to return me once each user who has timeend greater than the specific value

Comment: Use distinct in the query